# How to GetHlsUri in Azure Media Services V3

Tags: .net, azure-media-services

Azure media services V2, had IAsset.GetHlsUri and ILocator.GetHlsUri methods to get the URI for the HLS stream.  Those methods don't exist in V3.  How do you get the HLS uri in Azure Media Services V3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For .NET there is an example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/create-streaming-locator-build-url#net.  Basically you call ListPaths on the streaming locator and then either enumerate through the list for the HLS path or get the StreamingProtocol of HLS.  The REST doc is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/streaminglocators/listpaths.